# Print logs in Allure tear down phase using pyTest

Tags: python, pytest, allure

I am trying to print more logs in allure using pytest during the tear down phase.  For simplicity consider a conftest.py that has a fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture(name="summary", scope="session")
def result():
    class Summary():
        def __init__(self):
            pass

        def calculate(self):
            pass

        def __repr__(self):
            return "Printing summary..."

        def print_summary(self):
            print(self)

    obj = Summary()
    yield obj
    obj.calculate()
    obj.print_summary()
```

But all I get in Allure under 'Tear down' is `Summary::0`.  Is it possible to be able to print some logs here, like the "Printing summary..." in this example? Or should I just create another test like "test_summary" that basically logs the results?  I would rather not do that since it'll add another test and the test result summary of how many passed and failed would be kinda inaccurate.

Comment: there is no such thing as class fixtures, so this example wouldn't even be valid

Comment: sorry I accidentally deleted the function result